# What will happen if a bridge got a wrong mac record?

Tags: networking, switch, mac-address, bridging

Let's say there is host H1, H2, switch S1 S2, and S3, bridge B1, B2.

It is connected like this:

```
H1 - S1 - B1 - S2 - B2 - S3，
                |
               H2
```

H2 is sending frames to H1.

Then, we suddenly connect H1 to S3. Like:

```
S1 - B1 - S2 - B2 - S3 - H1，
           |
          H2
```

Then S2 is still sending frames to B1, because it doesn't know H1 is disconnected, and B1 don't know that too, it still forward the frames to S1, S1 receive an invalid destination mac frame, and it flood it to other ports rather than the port connected to B1.

So, does it means that H1 will never get frames sent to it unless it proactively send frames and the frame at least has to reach S2?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it "pro-actively send frames" when it does DHCP discovery at connection to S3?

Comment: "...H1 receive an invalid destination mac frame" ... What?

Comment: @StevenKath Sorry, H1 should be S1, has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your description of the scenario is correct in all aspects except for time.  The CAM table entry for H1 on S2 will expire if it doesn't receive any frames from H1 in the configured length of time, at which point it will broadcast those frames to all its ports.

However, as soon as H1 sends a frame via S3, either to H2 or to ffff.ffff.ffff, the CAM tables will update to reflect the topology change.

When the PHY layer drops on H1s old port on S1, S1 will delete all CAM table entries associated with that port, ensuring that subsequent frames addressed to H1 will be appropriately broadcast, so that other hosts connected to S1 will be able to get traffic to H1's new switch.

Answer (score 2):

@Nevin Williams's Answer is correct and you should upvote/accept that one.  I'd just like to add a couple notes that didn't fit in the Comments box:

1. Modern hosts typically send plenty of traffic (ARPs, DHCP requests, service discovery/advertisement traffic, etc.) when the link first comes up, so as it turns out, the problematic state doesn't usually last long at all.
2. The problem of hosts moving around a lot and causing the network's switches' filter tables (CAM tables) to be in the wrong state can be especially bad on 802.11 (Wi-Fi) networks, where every AP is a bridge (switch), and they are typically interconnected with wired switches. Enterprise-class Wi-Fi APs often do little tricks to help clear out the bad state quickly, like sending what IEEE 802.11F (the Inter- Access Point Protocol) calls a "Layer 2 Update Frame", which is a broadcast frame forged by the new AP to look like it came from the MAC address of the wireless client that just associated. This guarantees that the rest of the bridges/switches on the network see that the client's MAC address is now connected to the new AP, so that all the filter tables get update correctly, even if the wireless client didn't happen to send any multicast/broadcast traffic for itself.

Comment: +1, and ARP pretty much solves the problem as long as H1's ARP isn't cached by the relevant parties.  However, when people disconnect cables the only thing that could make the topology converge quickly is an STP TCN, but that's unlikely when almost everyone uses portfast by default these days.

Answer (score 0):

There are various things that can happen to restore connectivity

1. The entries in the bridging/switching tables can time out.
2. The entries in the ARP (or ND) tables can time out. When this happens H1 will send out a new broadcast which H2 will reply to
3. H1 sends a packet for some other reason.

In practice with PCs this tends not to be an issue, they are "chatty" enough that the switching tables are quickly updated. However I have had it be an issue with Ethernet-enabled test equipment.